# STDIN.read_nonblock messes up other programs after Ruby exits

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, terminal

I am writing an interactive terminal program in Ruby that sometimes runs `STDIN.read_nonblock(256)` to flush any buffered input from the user.

After running my Ruby program, if I run `git add -p` (another interactive program) in the same terminal and shell, then git malfunctions: it doesn't spend any time waiting for user input and instead just shows all of its prompts immediately and then exits.

Here is a shell session showing how I can reproduce this using Ubuntu 18.04, Ruby 2.6.3, and git 2.17.1:

```
$ mkdir testrepo && cd testrepo && git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/david/tmp/testrepo/.git/
$ touch foo.txt
$ git add foo.txt
$ echo hi > foo.txt
$ git add -p  # works fine
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index e69de29..45b983b 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hi
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]? q

$ ruby -v -e 'STDIN.read_nonblock(256)'
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-linux]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from -e:1:in `<main>'
    1: from <internal:prelude>:73:in `read_nonblock'
<internal:prelude>:73:in `__read_nonblock': Resource temporarily unavailable - read would block (IO::EAGAINWaitReadable)
$ git add -p  # bad: exits before waiting for input
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
index e69de29..45b983b 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ b/foo.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hi
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,e,?]? 
$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
```

Is there any workaround I can put in my Ruby program to prevent this from happening?  (I'm also interested in any insight about what might be happening.)

By the way, I noticed that a messed up terminal can be fixed by running `bash` to start a new shell, and then typing Ctrl+D exit that new shell.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `STDIN.read_nonblock`, Ruby uses the `fcntl` system call to set the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on its standard input file descriptor (2), and it never changes it back.  That descriptor is apparently shared with other processes, like your shell.

Unfortunately, git doesn't seem to turn off this flag, so it gets bad results when it tries to read user input from the terminal and the standard input is still in non-blocking mode.

I'm not sure if this is Git's fault or Ruby's fault, but you can fix it easily enough in the Ruby code by making a *new file descriptor* pointing to the standard input, and using that for all your non-blocking reads:

```rb
$stdin_nonblock ||= (File.open('/dev/stdin') rescue STDIN)
$stdin_nonblock.read_nonblock(256)
```

Warning: Unfortunately, you will not always have permission to open `/dev/stdin` (and you typically do not if you are a running in a shell started with `su`).  That is why I added `rescue STDIN` to the code.  I suspect `dup` would be a more reliable system call to use instead of `open`, if it works at all.

Comment: This is Ruby's "fault", because it sets the blocking flag. Many programs will fail after you run `read_nonblock`. Just try a simple `cat` on the command line and it will fail too. STDIN is just not supposed to be O_NONBLOCK.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your own answer, there is a way to reset O_NONBLOCK on the descriptor back to blocking. This also fixes the issue:

```
require 'fcntl'

flags = STDIN.fcntl(Fcntl::F_GETFL, 0)
STDIN.fcntl(Fcntl::F_SETFL, flags & ~Fcntl::O_NONBLOCK)
```

You have to run this code in an `ensure` block, because `read_nonblock` will not reset the flag back in any circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to bit-twiddling with `fcntl`, you can use [`io/nonblock`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/io/nonblock/rdoc/IO.html) to clear `O_NONBLOCK`:

```rb
require 'io/nonblock'
$stdin.nonblock {$stdin.read_nonblock(256)}
puts $stdin.nonblock? # false
```

`io/nonblock` is part of the [Ruby source tree](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/tree/v2_7_0/ext/io/nonblock) so it should always be available.